# Start an emulator as root from Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, adb, android-virtual-device

Currently, to start an emulator as root, I do these 3 well known steps:

1. `emulator -avd <name> -writable-system`
2. `adb root`
3. `adb remount`

Is it possible to configure some gradle or config files in Android Studio or AVD Manager in there, so it starts by running the emulator from Android Studio?